# Ant design drag and drop uploading after showing modal popup

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro, react-typescript

Im adding my react typescript project for the **[ant design file drag and drop upload](https://ant.design/components/upload/#components-upload-demo-fileList)** and **[modal](https://3x.ant.design/components/modal/)**. i try to do when i drag or upload file at moment   and just showing modal popup on the screen (don't want to display uploaded file just only showing  modal), i set the code but its not working , anyone know how to do that correctly

Thanks

**[stack blitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-hkm4tb)**

**code part here**

```
import { Upload, message,Modal, Button  } from 'antd';
import { InboxOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
const { Dragger } = Upload;

const props = {
  name: 'file',
  multiple: true,
  action: 'https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76',
  onChange(info) {
    const { status } = info.file;
    if (status !== 'uploading') {
      console.log(info.file, info.fileList);
    }
    if (status === 'done') {
      message.success(`${info.file.name} file uploaded successfully.`);
    } else if (status === 'error') {
      message.error(`${info.file.name} file upload failed.`);
    }
  },
};
interface AppProps { }
interface AppState {
  name: string; 

}

class App extends Component<AppProps, AppState> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
     visible: false
    };
  }

  //modal
 

  showModal = (any) => {
    this.setState({
      visible: "true",
    });
  };

  handleOk = e => {
    console.log(e);
    this.setState({
      visible: false,
    });
  };

  handleCancel = e => {
    console.log(e);
    this.setState({
      visible: false,
    });
  };


    

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <Dragger {...props} onClick={this.showModal}> 
    <p className="ant-upload-drag-icon">
      <InboxOutlined />
    </p>
    <p className="ant-upload-text">Click or drag file to this area to upload</p>
    <p className="ant-upload-hint">
      Support for a single or bulk upload. Strictly prohibit from uploading company data or other
      band files
    </p>
  </Dragger>


<div>
       
      
        <Modal
          title="Basic Modal"
          visible={this.state.visible}
          onOk={this.handleOk}
          onCancel={this.handleCancel}
        >
          <p>Some contents...</p>
          <p>Some contents...</p>
          <p>Some contents...</p>
        </Modal>
      </div>


      </div>




      
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution

i change this  `onClick={this.showModal}` to `onChange={this.showModal}`
and

put the state here

```
 onChange(info) {
    const { status } = info.file;
    if (status !== 'uploading') {
      console.log(info.file, info.fileList);
    }
    if (status === 'done') {
      message.success(`${info.file.name} file uploaded successfully.`);
    } else if (status === 'error') {
      message.error(`${info.file.name} file upload failed.`);
    }
  this.showModal
  },
};
```